# Как закрыть окно при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: java, javafx

```
@FXML
Button btnOK; // Для этой кнопки нужно сделать слушателя который будет закрывать это окно

private StorageVariables storageVariables=new StorageVariables();
private Stage stageMenu;
private String language;
private FXMLLoader fXMLLoader;

public void showMessageDialog()throws IOException{
    StorageVariables storageVariables = new StorageVariables();
    language=storageVariables.getLanguage();

    fXMLLoader = new FXMLLoader();

    fXMLLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MessageDialog.fxml"));

    Parent panel = null;
    try {
        panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MessageDialog.fxml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {}
    Scene scene=new Scene(panel,410,150);
    stageMenu=new Stage();
    stageMenu.setScene(scene);

    stageMenu.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    stageMenu.showAndWait();


}
```

// Этот метод - контроллер кнопки 'btnOK' обрабатывает нажатие кнопки

```
  public void inquiryQuestionBtnOK() {
    System.out.println(" *Кнопка 'btnOK' нажата");
    System.out.println("");

    stageMenu.close();
}
```

При нажатии на кнопку вылетает ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1456)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:96)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:83)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:523)
at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:438)
at sample.MyTool.showMessageDialog(MyTool.java:66)
at sample.ControllerCreateNewBuildMods.inquiryQuestionBtnReady(ControllerCreateNewBuildMods.java:168)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1453)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:28)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:96)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:384)
at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:83)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:523)
at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:438)
at sample.CreateNewBuildMods.showMenu(CreateNewBuildMods.java:37)
at sample.ControllerMainMenu.inquiryQuestionBtnMainMenuFirstBuild(ControllerMainMenu.java:286)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1453)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3369)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3209)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3164)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1582)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2267)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:17)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:67)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at    javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1453)
... 106 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sample.MyTool.inquiryQuestionBtnOK(MyTool.java:80)
... 116 more
```

Я не могу придумать, как это сделать. Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавить в обработчик события нажатия кнопки:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) btnOK.getScene().getWindow();
stage.close();
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!) Всё отлично работает